# Show only the first object with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xpath

After extracting data from a file in php with xpath.

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("CCV.xml");

    foreach ($xml->xpath('./section[@label="Education"]/section[@label="Degrees"]') as $details) {
            foreach ($details->field as $f) {
            $a = $f->attributes();
                if ('Degree Type'== $a['label']){
                    $x = $f->lov;
                    var_dump($x);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

The result looks like this

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[10]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '00000000000000000000000000000073' (length=32)
  public 0 => string 'Doctorate' (length=9)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '00000000000000000000000000000072' (length=32)
  public 0 => string 'Master's Thesis' (length=15)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[8]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string '00000000000000000000000000000084' (length=32)
  public 0 => string 'Bachelor's Equivalent' (length=21)
```

How can I return only the first object with **Doctorate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath you can wrap initial query within `()[1]` to get another xpath query that return only the first match :

```
(xpath/query/that/may/return/multiple/result)[1]
```

For this particular case it should be something like  :

```
(./section[@label="Education"]/section[@label="Degrees"])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would use

```
$x->0
```

Does this work?  0 being the key for the item you need.  Note it's not always best to use single letter variables, and especially in loops.  This can cause you some unnecessary confusion.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("CCV.xml");

foreach ($xml->xpath('./section[@label="Education"]/section[@label="Degrees"]') as $details)
{
    foreach ($details->field as $detailField)
    {
        $attribute = $detailField->attributes();
        if ('Degree Type' == $attribute['label']) 
        {
            $data = $detailField->0;
            var_dump($data);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, il does  not work. It gives me a error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '0' (T_LNUMBER), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\best_xml_file_extract_ever\test.php on line 15

Comment: `$x->0` is invalid syntax, you might want to try `$x->{'0'}`

Comment: It works now, I tried har07 solution. Thank you all for your contribution. I learned new staff today.